# "TemplateDoesNotExist at /" django react webpack project

Tags: reactjs, django, templates, webpack

I have a Django React app integrated using WebPack.

File structure as follows:

```
|--CSP
    |--api        /*django side*/
    |--CSP
        |--Settings.py
        |--urls.py
    |--frontend   /*react side*/
        |--dist   /*The template*/
            |--index.html
            |--bundle.js
        |--src
            |--components
                |--App.js
            |--index.js
            |--styles.css
        |--tailwind.config.js
        |--postcss.config.js
        |--urls.py
        |--views.py
        |--webpack.config.js
```

**Settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    
    'api.apps.ApiConfig',
    'rest_framework',
    'frontend.apps.FrontendConfig'
]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

**Views.py** (frontend)

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def index(request, *args, **kwargs):
    return render(request, '/csp/frontend/dist/index.html')
```

**urls.py** (frontend)

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index)
]
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  devServer: {
    static: {
      directory: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    port: 3000,
    open: true,
    hot: true,
    compress: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env.NODE_ENV' : JSON.stringify('development')
    })
],
}
```

[image: The error that i am getting]

Both react and django work perfectly on their own.

I tried moving `index.html` to a folder named template. same issue.

If there is any more files i need to include let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Django` `render()` function expects the path to be relative to the template directory.
For your current configuration, Django is trying to look for templates in the templates folder of each app, but you have placed the `index.html` file in the `dist` folder.

You can add the `frontend/dist` folder to the TEMPLATES configuration in `settings.py` file

```
import os

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'frontend/dist')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

**Then update your view file to this:**

```
def index(request, *args, **kwargs):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

This should fix the issue that you are facing.